# ldapdelete, want to remove all UID's of people OU, but preserve OU?

Tags: ldap

With this cli:

```
$ ldapdelete -ZZ -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake" -r  ou=People,dc=site,dc=fake
```

I remove all UID's of People, but the problem is it also removes People OU. I know it's easy to recreate a empty OU, but I'd like to remove all UID's of People OU, but preserve the actual People OU?

Comment: You could create a list of the DNs to delete using `ldapsearch` and pipe it to `ldapdelete` (without `-r`option).

Comment: Add as answer,so i can close the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, but I had to install and populate an LDAP server first to test the correct procedure. As `ldapdelete` reads the list of objects from STDIN if there are none presented on the command line (or in a file), you can use a pipe like

```
ldapsearch -ZZ -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake' \
-b 'ou=people,dc=site,dc=fake' -s one  dn |\
 grep dn: | cut -b 5- | ldapdelete -ZZ -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake'
```

This will ask you for the password twice; maybe you can use some other authentication method.

Instead of `-b ... -s one` you might have to define some other search base/scope/filter, depending on the directory structure.

I leave the part `grep dn: | cut -b 5- |` for those of you familiar to awk/sed/... any other constructs to optimize. I just like to keep things simple.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `cut -b 5-` is needed to get rid of the `0x0a` character in each line of output right after the `:` character. If you pipe that newline to `ldapdelete` or other utility (not sure how `grep` is dealing with it above), it's going to botch it. To forego passwords, and local to the LDAP server, you might be able to use: `ldapdelete  -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///`