# OpenLDAP: Deleted user is still listed in the group

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm currently doing openldap via command line. I added user John and added group devgroup, and I assigned John into devgroup group. When I deleted a user(John) via command line

```
ldapdelete -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local" 
"uid=john,dc=example,dc=local"
```

The user is gone but not in previously assigned group member (devgroup).

I noticed that the user and the group's assigned user have no linkage. Basically I can add any nonexistence user in the group. Is there way I can link these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're just deleting the user with that command but not all their entries from the OU. It's my understanding that LDAP doesn't maintain linkages with disparate objects like you're thinking, rather you're expected to do `ldapsearch`'s first to produce lists of objects that you then want to act on either using `ldapdelete` or `ldapmodify`.

We typically will write results from `ldapsearch` to `.ldif` files first and then act on them using `ldapmodify` or `ldapdelete`. You can however parse the output from `ldapsearch` and pipe it to `ldapmodify` as shown in this example from this U&L Q&A titled: [ldapdelete, want to remove all UID's of people OU, but preserve OU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413690/ldapdelete-want-to-remove-all-uids-of-people-ou-but-preserve-ou).

```
$ ldapsearch -ZZ -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake' \
   -b 'ou=people,dc=site,dc=fake' -s one  dn | \
   grep dn: | cut -b 5- | ldapdelete -ZZ -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake'
```

I believe you'll need to do something similar, finding all the group's that the user is a `memberUid` of, then pass that list to `ldapmodify`, and then run your `ldapdelete` command once they've been removed from all groups.

Incidentally to remove user's from a group:

```
dn: cn=Manager,dc=site,dc=fake
changetype: modify
delete: memberuid
memberuid: john
```

With respect to the `.ldif` files, the examples on this page titled: [Managing Users with Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)](https://simp.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.0-1/user_guide/User_Management/LDAP.html) are excellent. They show how to do all the basic operations with `.ldif` snippets which can be expanded upon to do operations across multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

As you already recognized group entries and their member entries are just that: Separate entries without hard linkage.

You have two options:

1. Implement your own script to remove a member entry and remove its DN from attribute *member* in the group entry.
2. Use OpenLDAP overlay [slapo-refint](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-refint) to let *slapd* remove the member reference from the group entry in case you delete the member entry.